# Number generator side by side

Tags: java, random, generator

i have a simple question: i have this number generator that gives me 20 random numbers one below the other. But I want the last 10 numbers side by side to the top 10 numbers (and not among each other). And the numbers should be separated by a ; sign.
(something like that:
0,26842 ; 0,57317

0,26841 ; 0,68413

0,98147 ; 0,39874

.....

```
import java.util.Random;
public class generator{

    public static void main(String []args){

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++ ){
      double random1 = 0.001 + Math.random() * (0.999 - 0.001);
      double random = 0.001 + Math.random() * (0.999 - 0.001);
      System.out.println(random1);
      System.out.println(random);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(random1 + " ; " + random);`

Comment: Since the numbers are **random**, it really, REALLY doesn't matter if the left number are the top 10 and the right numbers are the bottom 10, *or* the left number are the even numbers and the right numbers are the odd numbers. That requirement is just ... misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++ ){
      double random1 = 0.001 + Math.random() * (0.999 - 0.001);
      double random = 0.001 + Math.random() * (0.999 - 0.001);
      System.out.println(random1 + " ; " + random);
    }
  }
```

outputs

```
0.7111252532926727 ; 0.9224161624866566
0.1045487636779416 ; 0.9453595177537817
0.3364050083322531 ; 0.7834084543275484
0.7598622603023293 ; 0.30580035501190783
0.7195115086875891 ; 0.8302980914411036
0.913950475634719 ; 0.2963283928642933
0.9945639974861409 ; 0.8683929505272162
0.06537064833948451 ; 0.0019845517993550433
0.7734798245619805 ; 0.7177276949135386
0.7722443930857127 ; 0.3079818592445528
```

Let me know if thats what you wanted

Comment: Another option is: `System.out.printf("%f ; %f%n", random1, random)`